# Unable to reach text string held within a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to return the text stored in the "Badge Category" field, as per the below screen shot.

I can use `categorySelected = $('#badgeselect').text();` which returns both the "BadgeName" and Badge Category" text string, but they are then being saved in the Db as one "BadgeNameBadge Category"

I've tried `categorySelected = $('#badgeselect.category.tag.categorylabel').text();`but this returns a blank. Not sure what I'm doing wrong or missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors should have spaces between them. This denotes that they are nested:

```
 $('#badgeselect .categorylabel').text();
```

This means, select the element with class `categorylabel`, which is a descendant of an element with ID `badgeselect`.